# Unable to install .net core on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core

I followed all the steps from [microsoft .net core linux ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu)
Each step was ok until:

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.0.0
```

during this step I am receiving error:

```
Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-2.0.0'
```

I believe that I did everything before properle. 
During

```
sudo apt-get update
```

i see that it is reading from microsoft:

```
Stary:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
Stary:2 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease
Pobieranie:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease [70,3 kB]
Stary:4 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease
Stary:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-artful-prod artful InRelease
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Althought that on the microsoft site they wrote that you should install 2.0.0 version the proper is 2.0.2.
so when I used:

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.0.2
```

everything worked